# Симметричный блочный алгоритм Twofish-128, построение зависимых от ключа S блоков

Tags: шифрование

Здравствуйте!

Пожалуйста подскажите, как правильно должна работать процедура построения зависимых от ключа S блоков в Twofish-128. После чтения официальной спецификации Twofish-128, я понял, что после того как будет сгенерирован S вектор из 2 32 битных слов, нужно построить 4 S блока с 256 вхождениями, так как вовремя раундов шифрования каждый S блок на вход принимает 8 битное число (максимум 255 в десятичной системе) и производит 8 битный выход. В спецификации алгоритма Twofish-128 написано, что S блоки строятся путем вызова H функции, h (X, S), где L вектор в h функции используется как S вектор. Учитывая, что X служит как вход, он должен быть числом в районе от 0 до 255.

Псевдокод для построения 4-ех S блоков с 256 вхождений будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
UInt32[,] SBOX=new UInt32[4,256];
for(int i=0;i<4;i+=1)
{
for(int j=0;j<256;j+=1)
{
SBOX[i,j]=h(j,S);
}
}
```

Но я считаю, что это неправильно так как все 4 S блока будут иметь одинаковые значения так как j будет всегда в районе от 0 до 255 и S вектор фиксируется на все время работы алгоритма. Поэтому я не много запутался что именно должно браться за X как вход в h функции. Не могли бы вы сказать, как именно должна работать процедура построения 4 S блоков с 256 вхождениями. Может быть есть обучающий пример построения S блоков? Спасибо!

Comment: Взять описание алгоритма, его реализацию и посмотреть - не вариант?